Expo ReactViro - ios app crashing whenever position is added to reactvision/react-viro component (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)
I have spent hours on this and I am not able to figure this out.
I'm new to the AR lib and I have been trying to execute a simple application to see a strong in AR:
When I comment out 'position' the app runs with no issue.
    <ViroARScene>
      <ViroText
        text={"Hello World"}
        textLineBreakMode="Justify"
        textClipMode="ClipToBounds"
        color="#ff0000"
        width={2}
        height={2}
        position={[0, 2, 0]}
        style={{
          fontFamily: "Arial",
          fontSize: 15,
          // fontWeight: 400,
          fontStyle: "italic",
          color: "#0000FF",
          textAlignVertical:"top"
        }}
      />
     </ViroARScene>

Whenever position is passed, the ios app crashes.

package.json:
{
  "name": "arsocialstories2",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@reactvision/react-viro": "^2.41.6",
    "expo": "~51.0.26",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.14",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "^3.5.21",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "^13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

I am not very strong with swift, so this has been a pain to debug and check what is wrong
Any help is more than appreciated!

Ok I found the problem. Apparently, the latest version of "@reactvision/react-viro doesn't like expo 51 very much. I had to downgrade the expo to v50 and the issue went away!
